# Sequelize use between dates and then select Saturday only

Tags: sequelize.js, momentjs

```
model.findAll({
  where: {
    createdAt: {
     [Op.between]: [moment(req.params.startdate), moment(req.params.enddate).endOf('day')],
    },
  }
  .then((data) => {
     res.send(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => res.json(err));
})
```

**re.parmas.startdate** and **req.params.enddate** value will be fetched from the url which user will submit it. If the user selects startdate as '2021-05-01' and enddate as '2021-05-30'. Is there a way to get data between those day and count the data of **Saturday** only?

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest doing something like this.

```
model.findAll({
        where: {
          [Op.and] : {
            createdAt: {
              [Op.between]: [
                moment(req.params.startdate),
                moment(req.params.enddate).endOf("day"),
              ],
            },
            [Op.eq]: [sequelize.fn('weekday',sequelize.col('createdAt')),6]
        }
      }
  .then((data) => {
     res.send(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => res.json(err));
})
```